# C# GetFiles with extension and date filter

Tags: c#

I'm looking to only return .xls files that were created today from a folder containing multiple files and a range of dates.

I'm trying this:

```
FBD.SelectedPath = @"\\USMCO\Test\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
               .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date); 

 foreach (string file in files)
 {
     listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
 }
```

But get this error. CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I missing here?
TIA

Answer (score 2):

Try this you were missing to call **.ToArray()** Method

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
     .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).ToArray();
```

**Alternate way**

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("", "*.xls").Where(file => 
                                    new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Comment: @user2839067 Glad it helped please accept answer if was useful to you.

Comment: Why `ToArray` when the rest of the code simply do a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for pointing it out Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the enumerable to array by calling its ToArray method:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls").Where(file => 
    new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` extension method returns an `IEnumerable`, not an array.
But you don't need an array to execute a `foreach` loop, you can simply 
change `string[] files = Directory....` to `var files = Directory....` and continue with the rest of the code as is.

```
FBD.SelectedPath = @"\\USMCO\Test\";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
    .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date); 

 foreach (string file in files)
 {
     listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
 }
```

However, this can be done better, using [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Directory.GetFiles`, you can get the `FileInfo` directly instead of having to create one for each file:

```
FBD.SelectedPath = @"\\USMCO\Test\";
var files = DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
    .Where(file => new file.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date); 

 // file here is an instance of FileInfo!
 foreach (var file in files) 
 {
     // FileInfo.Name contains only the file name, not the entire path
     listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to select file names:

```
string[] files = Directory
    .GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
    .Select(path => new FileInfo(path)
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
    .Select(file => file.FullName)
    .ToArray();
```

Alternative solution:

```
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath)
    .GetFiles("*.xls")
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
    .Select(file => file.FullName)
    .ToArray();
```